# the "pyramid" of letters

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
var z = [];
for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++) z.push("a".repeat(i));
console.log(z.join("\n")+"\n"+"a".repeat(7)+z.reverse().splice(0,1).join("\n"));
```

I've made the code that does a "pyramid" of letters, that should look like this:

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaa
aaaa
aaa
aa
a
```

but it gives the output like this:

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

code here:

```
var z = [];
for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++) z.push("a".repeat(i));
console.log(z.join("\n")+"\n"+"a".repeat(7)+z.reverse().splice(0,1).join("\n"));
```

How to make the code work as expected?

P.S. I don't need separate the output, because instead of `console.log` method I use the API method `message.send`.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @FelixKling "Do my homework"

Comment: the question is 'how to make the code work as expected?'

Comment: @xShirase no, just askin' because i've got to make the bot workin' again and need some nodejs testing

Comment: `.splice(0,1)` returns an array of removed elements, not remaining elements. Remove it, add an extra `\n` and you are good to go. Why are you using `.splice` in the first place?

Comment: @FelixKling oh damn didn't think of that, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun way, using modulos, usable with any size.

```js
var len = 7;
var z = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 2*len; i++) 
  if(i<len)
    z.push("a".repeat(i%len+1));
  else if (i>len)
    z.push("a".repeat(len-i%len))
console.log(z.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `\n` after the central line, and you need to remove the splice.

```js
var z = [];
for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++) z.push("a".repeat(i));
console.log(
  z.join("\n")+"\n"+
  "a".repeat(7)+'\n'+
  z.reverse().join("\n")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

this way is possible:

```
var z = [];
for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++) z.push("a".repeat(i));
for(var i = 7; i > 0; i--) z.push("a".repeat(i));
console.log(z.join("\n"));
```

or:

```
var z = [];
for(var i = -7; i < 7; i++) z.push("a".repeat(7-Math.abs(i)));
console.log(z.join("\n"));
```

also try this very fast implementation:

```
console.log('a\naa\naaa\naaaa\naaaaa\naaaaaa\naaaaaaa\naaaaaa\naaaaa\naaaa\naaa\naa\na');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fn = (ch, len) => {
  let head = footer = '';
  Array(...Array(len).keys()).forEach((e, i) => {
    head += ch.repeat(i + 1) + `\n`;
    if(i !== 0)
      footer += ch.repeat(len - i) + `\n`;
  });
  return head + footer;
};

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = fn('a', 7);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) create an array of length 11. For each k in the callback push the number of `a` to the array with [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat). Join the array using `\n`:

```js
const result = Array.from({ length: 11 }, (v, k) => 'a'.repeat(k < 6 ? k + 1 : 11 - k)).join('\n');

console.log(result);
```